# Write Log file in installation folder selected by user

Tags: installshield

I have a query related to writing the Log File of my application.

I wants to write a log file in the Installation directory selected by the user.

So for that in setup's property `MSI Command Line Argument` I put a Value Like `[INSTALLDIR]ApplicationLog.log`. But it is not creating a log file in the installation directory.

Also I tried different ways like replacing `"[]" by "{}", "()", "%%"`. But still not getting any type of success.

Also I created a new PROPERTY and set that property's value to the path which I wants. But.........

Same thing I tried for Path variable also.

Somebody Please Help me.

Thanks and Regards,

Mohit Patel

Answer (score 2):

There's an ordering problem here. INSTALLDIR is not known until the installation really begins, but logging begins as the engine spins up and processes your command line and MSI file. Furthermore, INSTALLDIR is typically in an elevated area such as under the ProgramFilesFolder and thus cannot be written to by an unprivileged msiexec process (the recommended way to launch it).

If you instead want to write to an unprivileged location, one approach is to reference environment variables. For example, use locations such as `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\yourappinstall.log"` or `"%TEMP%\yourappinstall.log"`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. So please tell me how can i write a log file to a specific folder like [APPDATAFOLDER]...?

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks. Its working fine for me. But suppose I wants to put log file in %LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApplication\AppLog.log then it show me an error like path is not exist 'coz in LOCALAPPDATA folder "MyApplication" folder will not exist... Again Thanks for help.